# Hyphen rule for "thing doers"

Tags: hyphenation

I'm confident in my abilities regarding where to place and not place hyphens except in one area: when you have a phrase that consists of a noun and a noun that consists of a verb with -er at the end, does that get a hyphen?

For instance, if I'm talking about a scheme that will give you twice as much money as you had before, is that a "money doubler" or is it a "money-doubler"? Some instances of this sort of phrase just turn it into one word like "heartbreaker" or "homemaker."

I have no idea what to call this, so I don't know what to Google. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hyphenation, especially in such cases, is more of a matter of disambiguation and readability, than one of grammar. Certain phrases on regular use may become idiomatic, gain a hyphen to bind together, and eventually even merge into a single word. *Home maker*, *home-maker* and *homemaker* are all in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of fluidity to compound words. Though you will see *cry-baby* and *low-life* and *to-day* seldom today, they used to be common. (Not all words go this way -- we used to get off our *hobby-horse* and eat some *ice-cream*, but these are largely separated by a space to-day.)

I would consider the no-space, no-hyphen forms like *homemaker* and *chickpea* to be reserved for the most familiar terms which happen case-by-case.

I don't think there is a general rule. *The New York Times Manual of Style* lists dozens upon dozens of specific word combinations so that their editors know how to speak of *airfields*, *air-conditioners*, and *air rifles*.

Comment: Can this help the OP - https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp

Comment: Do people use 'to-day'?

Comment: @RamPillai "to-day" used to be the standard way of writing it, but it's  *extremely* uncommon now.

Comment: @RamPillai Actually, quite a bit: Rules 2a and 2b at the beginning. Specifically, 
I